# Why does "final" on a POJO throw compile error on a "new" with inline setters?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

Why can I not write an "inline" object creator on a final class?

Here is the (non final) version of the class.

```
public class ValidationResult {

    private boolean isValid;

    private int statusCode;

    private String statusMessage;

    public boolean isValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    public void setValid(boolean valid) {
        isValid = valid;
    }

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public String getStatusMessage() {
        return statusMessage;
    }

    public void setStatusMessage(String statusMessage) {
        this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
    }
}
```

Here is the new with inline setters.

```
                ValidationResult vr = new ValidationResult() {{
                    setStatusCode(55555);
                    setValid(false);
                    setStatusMessage("This snipplet is working");
                }};
```

I make the simple POJO class "final"

```
public final class ValidationResult {

    private boolean isValid;

    private int statusCode;

    private String statusMessage;

    public boolean isValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    public void setValid(boolean valid) {
        isValid = valid;
    }

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public String getStatusMessage() {
        return statusMessage;
    }

    public void setStatusMessage(String statusMessage) {
        this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
    }
}
```

And with the same new-inline

```
                ValidationResult vr = new ValidationResult() {{
                    setStatusCode(55555);
                    setValid(false);
                    setStatusMessage("Huh??");
                }};
```

I get a

> Error:(23, 41) java: cannot inherit from final
> com.me.myproject.domain.ValidationResult

"cannot inherit" ?

Huh??

Comment: Because with the curly braces you’re defining an anonymous subclass.

Comment: `{{ }}` is a nasty hack for initialisation that works by creating an anonymous subclass of the declared type. You can't create an anonymous subclass of a final class. If you didn't know it was doing that, you probably shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @khelwood: for that matter even if we know what it does it’s better not to use it.

Comment: @NathanHughes That too

Comment: The outer curly braces following the class name indicate an anonymous class definition. The inner braces are the instance initializer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use double braces initialization, behind the scene you're making an anonymous inner class that extends `ValidationResult` class.

In Java, you're not allowed to extend classes with `final` keyword, hence the compilation error you're seeing.

[Also, keep in mind the following drawbacks when using double braces initialization](https://www.baeldung.com/java-double-brace-initialization):

> - Obscure, not widely known way to do the initialization
> - It creates an extra class every time we use it
> - Doesn’t support the use of the “diamond operator” – a feature introduced in Java 7
> - Doesn't work if the class we are trying to extend is marked final
> - Holds a hidden reference to the enclosing instance, which may cause memory leaks

Comment: Starting with Java 9, it will work with the diamond operator. But it's still not recommended. Mind that it will not only have a hidden reference to the enclosing instance, but also to everything it uses in the initializer, e.g. when you use `new ArrayList<>() { add(a); }`, it will keep a hidden reference to whatever `a` referenced at the time of construction, even when that object has been removed from the list. In other words, after calling `clear()` on it, the list appears to be empty, but still keeps a hidden reference to that object.

Comment: Thanks for answer and repercussions outside of the anonymous class thing.